# Merge url of angular and Django

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, django-urls, angularjs-routing

What is the standard way to define urls when using Django,AngularJS and Django-Rest-Framework ?

In other way, is it possible to define SPA urls commonly instead of defining it in both `Angular` and `Django` ?

Answer (score 2):

[Django-Angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) actually provides javascript handlers that operate in a similar fashion to the `{% url ... %}` template tags and django `reverse` functions.

[From the django-angular readthedocs on Managing URLs](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reverse-urls.html#reverse-urls):

> > Starting with version 0.8, django-angular provides a new way to handle URLs, which offers the reversing functionality directly to AngularJS modules.
>
> This service is provided by `djangoUrl.reverse(name, args_or_kwargs)` method. It behaves exactly like [Django’s URL template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

[Django-Angular](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) provides a lot of helper functions around integrating Django and Angular, and it probably would you checking out.